# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED for a keyword search

Tags: google-chrome, dns, microsoft-edge

When I type jira, it gets redirected to jira/ and ends up with an error page. This started after I mistakenly clicked `Did you mean ... jira/?`.

```
Hmmm… can't reach this page jira’s server IP address could not be found.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS settings.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Flushing the DNS on `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` or running `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` do not seem to help. How I can go back to searching my keyword again?

Comment: I dont think this is a DNS problem.  Have you flyshed your browser cache?

Comment: @davidgo I am hoping to resolve it without flushing the browser cache as they will reset a lot of things